# PHP multiple __toString methods, switched in the runtime

Tags: php, tostring

I need different `__toString()` for the same class.

## Example

I have the Person class that contains a firstname and a surname. According to current context I wish to display it with different order, formatting etc. Imagine three scenarios:

- the firstname comes first, followed by space and surname `Thomas Müller`
- the surname comes first and uppercased, followed by space and the firstname `MÜLLER Thomas`
- the surname comes first, followed by comma, then space and the firstname `Müller, Thomas`

I can create public methods for each display.

```
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<?php
class Person
{
  protected $firstname;
  protected $surname;

  public function __construct($firstname, $surname)
  {
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
    $this->surname = $surname;
  }

  public function toStringWithFirstnameFirst()
  {
    return $this->firstname . " " . $this->surname;
  }

  public function toStringWithSurnameFirstUppercase()
  {
    $surnameConverted = mb_convert_case($this->surname, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
    return $surnameConverted . " " . $this->firstname;
  }

  public function toStringWithSurnameFirstAndFirstnameAfterComma()
  {
    return $this->surname . ", " . $this->firstname;
  }
}

$person = new Person("Thomas", "Müller");
echo $person->toStringWithFirstnameFirst() . "<br/>";
echo $person->toStringWithSurnameFirstUppercase() . "<br/>";
echo $person->toStringWithSurnameFirstAndFirstnameAfterComma() . "<br/>";
?>
```

But I stuck with `DescriptiveButVeryLongToStringMethodNames`.
 I wish to have simply `echo $person;` in the code.

## Solution: store the class state in the static members

My first solution is to place `switch-case` inside `__toString()` method. Conditional statement depends on the class state stored in the static variable `self::$chosenToStringMethod`. So I need static method to set the class state and also class constants that serve as enums.

```
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<?php
class Person
{
  protected $firstname;
  protected $surname;

  const PRINT_FIRSTNAME_FIRST = 1;
  const PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_UPPERCASE = 2;
  const PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_FIRSTNAME_AFTER_COMMA = 3;

  static private $chosenToStringMethod;

  public function __construct($firstname, $surname)
  {
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
    $this->surname = $surname;
  }

  static public function setToStringMethod($choice)
  {
    self::$chosenToStringMethod = $choice;
  }

  private function toStringWithFirstnameFirst()
  {
    return $this->firstname . " " . $this->surname;
  }

  private function toStringWithSurnameFirstUppercase()
  {
    $surnameConverted = mb_convert_case($this->surname, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
    return $surnameConverted . " " . $this->firstname;
  }

  private function toStringWithSurnameFirstAndFirstnameAfterComma()
  {
    return $this->surname . ", " . $this->firstname;
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
    switch (self::$chosenToStringMethod) {
      case self::PRINT_FIRSTNAME_FIRST:
        return $this->toStringWithFirstnameFirst();
        break;
      case self::PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_UPPERCASE:
        return $this->toStringWithSurnameFirstUppercase();
        break;
      case self::PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_FIRSTNAME_AFTER_COMMA:
        return $this->toStringWithSurnameFirstAndFirstnameAfterComma();
        break;
      default:
        return "No __toString method set";
        break;
    }
  }
}

$person = new Person("Thomas", "Müller");
echo $person . "<br/>";
Person::setToStringMethod(Person::PRINT_FIRSTNAME_FIRST);
echo $person . "<br/>";
Person::setToStringMethod(Person::PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_UPPERCASE);
echo $person . "<br/>";
Person::setToStringMethod(Person::PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_FIRSTNAME_AFTER_COMMA);
echo $person . "<br/>";
?>
```

I see some disadvantages of this solution:

- `Person` class is getting heavy
- `switch-case` statements can hide some mistakes

I wish `Person` class containing only its own functionality not all kinds of toStrings. I would rather have some pattern that can dynamically inject `__toString()`.

Comment: Well, where and how are you deciding which format to output? Can that change from one line to the next? Then is makes no sense having a global config set for that. How about `echo $person->name(Person::FORMAL)`; i.e. pass a parameter with a bunch of pre-defined possible formats?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're expecting here; your first disadvantage seems to be inevitable, and I don't understand what you mean by the second. If there was some way to "dynamically inject `__toString`", the code for that would live somewhere. And a `switch` statement seems no more likely to hide mistakes than any other implementation.

Comment: Or have a dedicated, configurable *renderer*. It seems overhead, but it makes things easy in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I assume the reason, why you're asking, is that you'd like to keep things clean but there's no way to set __toString() method to an existing object, so the best solution would be to split functionality

first create a PersonRender:

```
class PersonRender 
{
    const PRINT_FIRSTNAME_FIRST = 1;
    const PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_UPPERCASE = 2;
    const PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_FIRSTNAME_AFTER_COMMA = 3;

    static public $chosenToStringMethod;

    private $person;

    public function __construct($person) 
    {
        $this->person = $person;
    }

    public function render() 
    {
        switch (self::$chosenToStringMethod) 
        {
            case self::PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_UPPERCASE :
                return $this->toStringWithSurnameFirstUppercase();
            case self::PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_FIRSTNAME_AFTER_COMMA :
                return $this->toStringWithSurnameFirstAndFirstnameAfterComma();
            default :
                return $this->toStringWithFirstnameFirst();
        }
    }

    private function toStringWithFirstnameFirst()
    {
        return "{$this->person->firstname} {$this->person->surname}";
    }

    private function toStringWithSurnameFirstUppercase()
    {
        $surnameConverted = mb_convert_case($this->person->surname, MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
        return "{$surnameConverted} {$this->person->firstname}";
    }

    private function toStringWithSurnameFirstAndFirstnameAfterComma()
    {
        return "{$this->person->surname}, {$this->person->firstname}";
    }

}
```

and then the Person class:

```
class Person 
{

    public $firstname, $surname;

    public function __construct($firstname, $surname) 
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        $render = new PersonRender($this);
        return $render->render();
    }
}
```

and a little test:

```
$person = new Person('Foo', 'Bar');
echo $person;
echo '<hr />';
PersonRender::$chosenToStringMethod = PersonRender::PRINT_SURNAME_FIRST_UPPERCASE;
echo $person;
```

**EDIT 1**
to keep the code clean, the Person entity class should of course have private props firstname and surename and methods set and get

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the most clean way would be to just provide getter for firstname and surname and manually assemble the strings where you need them. In your current solutions you are just polluting your workspace with unnecessary classes and make the class `Person` more complex than it should be.